# Where do I attach the rails for the keyboard tray on this desk?

Tags: desk

First off - this is the final look of the desk:

[image]

The problem is that the white rails for the keyboard tray - I don't know where to attach them to the desk. I have three 727x510 milimeter planks that the top plank(the 1100x590 one) should be attached to. However I'm not sure which way should be up or down. Te 350 milimeter rail should be attached like you see on the picture, but I can't find the proper spots. Maybe I have them the wrong way? All three planks have four holes at the top which match the three lines of holes on the top plank, so I assumed that's where they attach to it and that's their top part. Their other part is smooth. Here is what I mean:

Top part:
[image]

Bottom part:
[image]

On the other hand, i have these "legs" that look like they match the holes in the "top part":

[image]

Here are pictures of the three planks front and back.

Front:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Back:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The order of the planks is the same on both the front and back pics. Here is the top plank's bottom side:

[image]

Can anyone give me a clue on which direction they should all be facing and where to put the tray rail? It doesn't match any 2 holes and if I screw it to a single hole it'll just rotate around it...that's not right.

Answer (score 1):

Assemble the rest of the desk, it should become self explanatory with what holes are left. This is probably contrary to the instructions, but you will be able to reach inside to attach the drawer slides later.

Picture 1 is the right side face of the middle upright

Picture 2 is the inside face of the left upright.

Picture 3 is the inside face of the right upright.

The feet go on the sides opposite the embedded metal lock nuts.

[image: RTFM]

Comment: So it's certain that the side with the holes is up, right? the one that matches the pattern on the bottom of the top plank?

Comment: The sides are the ones with the metal lock nuts in them (the first 3 pictures), the top (the last picture) only has holes in it (for the fasteners that go into the lock nuts). @the_relinquisher